# how to check var's in jquery

Tags: jquery, variables

i have this script:

```
var display = '<div class="uploadData" id="pxupload'+ itr +'_text">';
```

and i want to check if the `div` from `diplay` exists. Something like this:

```
if (display = null){
        $("#px_display").append(display);
    }else if  (display != null) {
        $(config.buttonClear).trigger('click');
    }
```

I don't know if the statement is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best you could do is...

```
var display = '<div class="uploadData" id="pxupload'+ itr +'_text">';

var id = $(display).attr('id');

if ($('#' + id).length) {
   // Some element with the same id attribute exists.
}
```

This, of course, is not too accurate.

It would be better if you made that variable first, like so...

```
var displayId = 'pxupload' + itr;

if ($('#' + displayId).length) {
   // Some element with the same id attribute exists.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

since the ID will be unique and constructible, can you do something like:

```
if($("#pxupload" + itr + "_text") == null){
        $("#px_display").append(display);
}else if  (display != null) {
    $(config.buttonClear).trigger('click');
}
```